# Unknown circular schematic symbol

Tags: symbol, schematic

This is the symbol that I do not know what it means.
The top trace leads to a polarized capacitor

[image: top trace leads to a polarized capacitor]

Comment: Surely the complete circuit gives a clue that it's a microphone or at least an audio or vibration transducer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the symbol for an electret microphone.

Here are the external and internal schematics.

[image]
[image]